# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table './quotes/actions.frm' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-workbench

When I am heading to create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE actions ( A_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type ENUM('rate','report','submit','edit','delete') NOT NULL,
    Q_id int NOT NULL,
    U_id int NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    time TIME NOT NULL,
    rate tinyint(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (A_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Question FOREIGN KEY (Q_id) REFERENCES questions(P_id));
```

Shows this error:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table './quotes/actions.frm' (errno: 150)
>   `----------`
>   With reference to
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

InnoDB does not currently support foreign keys for tables with user-defined partitioning. This includes both parent and child tables.

Can anyone explain the above lines.

I can't understand why am I seeing this.

Comment: `show engine innodb status;`

Comment: Does your `questions` table have any partitioning?

Comment: When ever i type Engine=innoDB at the end it is going to show this error. So I went to docs and i saw about partitioning. My table has no partitioning. But i want to know what is user defined partitioning as defined in my question referred from mysql docs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

150 is usually fixed by CREATEing the tables in a different order.  If the does not suffice (eg, circular FKs), use ENABLE/DISABLE FOREIGN KEYS.

PARTITION... True.  The current design of PARTITIONing does not allow for arbitrary UNIQUE KEYS or FOREIGN KEYS.  This is not likely to be changed until (perhaps) 5.8.